# Parsing mutliple double quoted filename using Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I just want to take a line containing multiple filenames using enclosed by double quotes (this is what Windows seem to use when multiple files are selected in a file dialog" and get them back as separate strings.

i.e given

```
"C:\MusicMatched2\Gold Greatest Hits" "C:\MusicMatched2\The Trials of Van Occupanther"
```

I want to decode that to two strings:

```
C:\MusicMatched2\Gold Greatest Hits
C:\MusicMatched2\The Trials of Van Occupanther
```

I usually use String.split() but thats no good in this instance, can anyone help

**Answer**, the regexp given in the answer worked implemented as follows:

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]++)\"");
        Matcher matcher =p.matcher("C:\MusicMatched2\Gold Greatest Hits" "C:\MusicMatched2\The Trials of Van Occupanther");
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
```

Comment: Does using `"\"(\\s+\")?"` with a split work ?

Comment: Wouldn't you get multiple "args"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most faster pattern is probably:

```
"\"([^\"]++)\""
```

with find method, the result is in capturing group 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "\"C:\\MusicMatched2\\Gold Greatest Hits\" \"C:\\MusicMatched2\\The Trials of Van Occupanther\"";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.*?)\"");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```